# Order of precedence:  in $ab^{c}$, which operation goes first?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If you have 
$$x^3(x^2 + 1)^{-\frac{1}{2}},$$
os the power or the product calculated first? I'm assuming the power comes first but I don't like to just assume.

Comment: the only thing raised to the $-1/2$ is the $x^2+1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powers have precedence over multiplication.  (Powers are applied first.)

It's just like how the only thing squared in $x y^2$ is the $y$.

Answer (score 2):

Exponentiation is done before multiplication, so it should not be "an assumption".  Of course, the + is done before the exponentiation, unless you are planning to turn it into a series or something.

Answer (score 0):

Indices before multiplication.

$$x^3(x^2 + 1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = x^3((x^2 + 1)^{-\frac{1}{2}})$$

You can remember the order of precedence by the acronym 'BIDMAS': Brackets, Indices, Division, Multiplication, Addition, Subtraction.